# Has anyone got Xdebug working with Laravel Octane?

Tags: laravel, xdebug, swoole, laravel-octane

We are using Laravel Octane (with Swoole) and are struggling to get Xdebug working consistently (PhpStorm and Docker). It seems to work (hits breakpoints) and then stops when we make code changes.

Is this something to do with Swoole? Do we need to be using Yet Another Swoole Debugger?

Answer (score 1):

According to the OpenSwoole documentation, swoole is not compatible with xdebug.

Generally, PHP works in a request/response mode. All of the PHP extensions assume that this is how PHP will run. And that's not how swoole works.
Apart from xdebug, more extensions will not work when you use swoole: phptrace, aop (Aspect Oriented Programming), xhprof, Phalcon, BlackFire, Datadog, Newrelic? (swoole is not on the list of officially supported web servers).

While the situation may improve over time, currently, many "low level" extensions will not be compatible with swoole.

Comment: This answer is false. This can be observed by using xdebug with reactphp which also acts as a server process rather than as a fcgi request handler. The problem with swoole is that it uses an internal thread pool for processing events within it's server OR forks and distributes events to handlers within the resulting process pool. xdebug was not designed with this in mind even though PHP has been able to fork within itself for over 2 decades. See this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926701/can-xdebug-debug-a-php-cli-script-that-uses-pcntl-fork

Answer (score 0):

If you use swoole, the PHP works a bit differently. I jus found [this](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=2161) bug report, where is a suggestion: "use 'xdebug_break()'"
I tested on a fresh setup (latest version of swoole and xdebug) with Laravel Octane using the watch feature.
Instead of placing a break point,just call the "xdebug_break()" method. As I tested, it works well.

[Using Xdebug with Swoole in PHPSTORM (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnMQT.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).